# deleting line numbers in sed or awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file in which each line begins with a number 0-243, and it restarts from 0-243 for 2000 times. How can I delete line numbers with awk or preferably sed?
I used this command in awk but it doesn't work :  '{$1=$2= " "; $0=$0; $1=$1}1'

Comment: Can you show an example? What follows the initial numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  The example you give should delete the 1st two columns, and I agree that that does not seem to be what you want, but it's not at all clear to me why you thought that code would do anything other than what it does.

Comment: This is what you need, `awk '{$1 = ""; print $0;}' file` Assuming, your file is formatted with default IFS which we will not know, unless you provide the sample file

Comment: Or `sed 's/[0-9]*//'` (This requires that there be no whitespace before the number and will remove numbers greater than 243)

Comment: @ Inian: thanks Inian. it was the one i wanted!

Comment: @mary: I will post the same as an answer below, so that the post can be deemed solved, and people find it more relevant/useful if they find the accepted symbol for the answers!

Comment: When your car breaks down and you take it to a mechanic do you just say "it doesn't work" and expect the mechanic to figure out the problem and fix it based on just that? No? Then don't do that when you're asking people to help you fix your software either. Tell us in what way it doesn't work - wrong output, no output error message, core dump, something else? Also, edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output as what you have told us so far could mean any one of several things about your input file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do, provided there are no other numbers at the beginning of the line:

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+//'
```